# Round (epoch) time to highest minute

Tags: javascript, date, rounding, epoch, iso

I'm trying to get the epoch time from exactly 1 hour ago, rounded to the highest minute.
E.g: **19:17:01** should become **19:18:00** & **19:17:59** should become **19:18:00** etc.

I already know how to convert Date (Minus 1 hour) to Epoch:

```
var dat = new Date();
dat.setHours( dat.getHours() - 1 );
var epochstart = Date.parse(dat)
console.log(epochstart) //Returns e.g. 19:17:01 in epoch (Milliseconds) time
```

This works and everything but how would I round the date to the minute UP?

And, if possible, I want to convert the milliseconds to seconds (I can just remove the last 3 chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you managed to change the hour, similarly, you can change the minutes and seconds. Based on your ask, below is a possible solution:

```js
let dat = new Date();
dat.setHours(dat.getHours() - 1);

if (dat.getSeconds() > 0) {
  dat.setMinutes(dat.getMinutes() + 1);
  dat.setSeconds(0);
}

const epochstart = Date.parse(dat);

console.log(dat.toString());
console.log(epochstart);
```

As for converting milliseconds to seconds, divide `epochstart` by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to round the time value up to the nearest full minute, which will also zero the seconds and milliseconds at the same time:

```js
/* Set date to next full minute or current time
 * if at exctly 0 minutes and 0 milliseconds
 * @param {Date} date - start date
 * @returns {Date} new Date set to next full minute
*/
function getNextFullMinute(date) {
  return new Date(date - (date % 6e4) + 6e4);
}

// Format options
let dateOpts = {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute:'2-digit',
  hour12: false
};

// Get a Date set to the start of the next minute
let date = getNextFullMinute(new Date());
console.log(`The next full minute is at ${date.toLocaleString(void 0, dateOpts)}.`);
```